# How to compress lua to numbers

Tags: lua

just been wondering on how do i get something like this.

[image]

```
load("\105\73\103\52\118\108\56\118\101\54\49\109\110\104\77\114\81\73\111\66\105\105\71\48\111\122\84\48\122\103\119\113\80\101\104\51\116\70\105\100\83\71\68\89\52\88\67\71\98\81\57\111\61\95\71\59\98\113\105\49\113\80\98\86\51\66\74\66\104\49\56\54\70\109\109\100\112\52\82\78\68\110\107\100\103\101\56\75\109\113\99\51\110\80\
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the load function? Here it is most likely compiled lua code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [string.dump](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.dump), which "returns a string containing a binary representation (a binary chunk) of the given function, so that a later load on this string returns a copy of the function (but with new upvalues)."